# Is there an advantage to layering leiningen projects?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

This is not a problem question, but a use of tools -- leiningen -- question.

Is there an advantage to creating hierarchical lein projects under one main project, and, if so, what is that advantage?

If I create a project using `lein new bene-cmp`, which is a Clojure "main" program

```
(defproject bene-cmp "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "This is the main benetrak/GIC comparison program."
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.2"]
                 [bene-csv "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [util "1.0.4-SNAPSHOT"]]

  :omit-source true
  :main bene-cmp.core)
```

and I want to write some Clojure scripts that will sanitize input files that will eventually be fed into bene-cmp by a bash script, should these be projects at the same level as bene-cmp, or under the bene-cmp project, and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always look at the release cycle of the projects to determine if they are subprojects or "same level" projects. If you are always going to release the bene-sanitizers at the same time that bene-cmp, then they are subprojects or even just namespaces in the bene-cmp.